# SVG get right mime type when uploading

Tags: php, symfony, php-7

When I upload a SVG to my Symfony application the mimetype is `text/html` but it should be `image/svg+xml`. Did I miss to configure something in my php to detect the right mimetype?

Example Code:

```
public function uploadAction(Request $request) 
{
    $uploadFile = $request->files->get($name);

    $mimeType = $uploadedFile->getMimeType();
    // or $mimeType = mime_content_type($uploadedFile->getPathname());
    // both return "text/html" instead of "image/svg+xml"

    return new Response($mimeType);
}
```

I used the Wiki example of svg to test it: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/02/SVG_logo.svg

Comment: Show us some code and SVG source itself.

Comment: @mitkosoft example code and example svg added.